# If I need to create a large format poster @ 120 dpi can the image on the poster be @ 120 dpi as well?

Tags: images, resolution, dpi

If I need to create a large format poster that's supposed to be printed at 120 dpi can the image on the poster have an effective DPI of 120 dpi as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Printing at X resolution, placed images will not benefit from being greater than X effective resolution. 
If there is a forced limitation on the resolution at the output, then everything will end up at that resolution anyway. In fact, there may be a benefit in starting out with the exact output resolution because then you at least have some control over how the images are subsampled, rather than leaving that choice up to the RIP or whatever software you use to export the subsampled production file.